# Can't successfully delete file on btrfs filesystem

Tags: linux, filesystems, btrfs

I've got a 4 GB file in a BTRFS file system that just won't go away. I have deleted it multiple times, I've even echo'd to it, and it keeps coming back. The `ls -l` is:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mark mark 4072587264 Oct 13 10:19 Inglourious.Basterds.2009.1080p.BluRay.10bit.HEVC.6CH-MkvCage.ws.mkv
```

Anybody know how to get rid of it? Thanks.

Comment: Is there an error when you execute `rm "Inglourious.Basterds.2009.1080p.BluRay.10bit.HEVC.6CH-MkvCage.ws.mkv"`?

Comment: No, no error.  It looks as though it were deleted, but after cd'ing out and back again it shows up.

Comment: Would you show `ls -l /full/path/to/Inglourious.Basterds.2009.1080p.BluRay.10bit.HEVC.6CH-MkvCage.ws.mkv` before and after `rm -v /full/path/to/Inglourious.Basterds.2009.1080p.BluRay.10bit.HEVC.6CH-MkvCage.ws.mkv`?

Comment: File suddenly disappeared.  Thanks.